# How do I call a function within another function when the data I need is in the global scope?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, scope

I have a set of card objects that I map over.
When I click on a card it adds the `selected` class which in turn gives it a border to show the user it is selected, it also adds the id of the card to the `selectedCards` `useState` array.

WHAT I WANT TO HAPPEN:

Each card object has a `creditAvailable` key  state which is equal to a figure.
On selection (click) of the card, in addition to selecting the card I would also like to add up the `creditAvailable` and display it on the screen. and when I unselect the card I would like the figure to go down.

WHAT I HAVE TRIED:

I thought it would be as simple as calling the function to add up the credit inside the first function which selects the card, however when console logging inside the first function I see that the state has not yet updated. (scope).

I then tried to call the function outside of the first function but it gave me an infinite loop. Here is my code.
Any ideas? Thanks

```
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);
  const [selectedCards, setSelectedCards] = useState([]);
  const [total, setTotal] = useState();
```

```
const handleSelectCard = (id) => {
   if (selectedCards.includes(id)) {
     const filteredIds = selectedCards.filter((c) => c !== id);
     setSelectedCards([...filteredIds]);
   } else {
     setSelectedCards([...selectedCards, id]);
   }
   // addUpCreditAvailable(); // nothing happens
   console.log(selectedCards); // []
 };
```

```
console.log(selectedCards) // [1] for example. This is in the global scope

  const addUpCreditAvailable = () => {
    console.log("inside add up credit");
    const chosenCards = selectedCards.map((id) => {
      const foundCard = allCards.find((card) => {
        return card.id === id;
      });
      return foundCard; 
    });
    const result = chosenCards.reduce((acc, card) => {
      return acc + card.creditAvailable;
    }, 0);
     setTotal(result);

    return result;
  };
```

```
 return (
    <div className="Container">
      <UserInputForm submitData={handleSubmitData} />
      <h1> Cards available to you displayed are below!</h1>
      {cards.map(
        ({
          id,
          name,
          number,
          apr,
          balanceTransfer,
          purchaseDuration,
          creditAvailable,
          expiry,
        }) => (
          <CreditCard
            key={id}
            name={name}
            number={number}
            apr={apr}
            balanceTransferDuration={balanceTransfer}
            purchaseOfferDuration={purchaseDuration}
            creditAvailable={creditAvailable}
            expiry={expiry}
            onClickCard={() => handleSelectCard(id)}
            selected={selectedCards.includes(id)}
          />
        )
      )}
   <span> £{total}</span>
)}
```

Comment: `total` should not be a state. Just calculate it based on `selectedCards`.

Comment: @JonasWilms but isn't that what I am doing in the `addUpCreditAvailable` function? I am calculating figure and returning the result... Do you mean i should get rid of `setTotal(result);` and the useState for total?

Comment: yes, exactly. Also the `setSelectedCards([...filteredIds]);` shouldnt be directly in the component.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with the help from above. As Wilms said i had to return the result of the `handleSelectCard` function and return the result of the `addUpCredit` function. Then I called the `addUpCreditAvailable` with the `selectedCards` state and stored the result in a variable which i then displayed in my `render` method.

```
 const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);
  const [selectedCards, setSelectedCards] = useState([]);

  const handleSelectCard = (id) => {
    if (selectedCards.includes(id)) {
      const filteredIds = selectedCards.filter((c) => c !== id);
      setSelectedCards([...filteredIds]);
    } else {
      setSelectedCards([...selectedCards, id]);
    }
    return selectedCards;
  };

  const addUpCreditAvailable = (selectedCards) => {
    const chosenCards = selectedCards.map((id) => {
      const foundCard = allCards.find((card) => {
        return card.id === id;
      });
      return foundCard;
    });

    const result = chosenCards.reduce((acc, card) => {
      return acc + card.creditAvailable;
    }, 0);
    return result;
  };

  const totalCredit = addUpCreditAvailable(selectedCards);
```

render method:

```
render (
[...]
 {selectedCards.length && (
        <div className={bem(baseClass, "total-credit")}>
          Total Credit available: £{totalCredit}
        </div>
      )}

[...]
)
```